# Failing HDD Data Recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I'm not sure if this is the correct forum, but it seemed to be the closest I could find. I have an external hard drive enclosure with a WD green 2TB HDD that no longer works. I've removed it from the enclosure and have it connected with a usable sata>USB3 connector. The HDD spins up, and doesn't make much noise otherwise. It will occasionally be found for 4-5 seconds, then disappear again for several minutes. Any thoughts on how to recover the data on this drive?

Edit: working with Ubuntu 18.04. Can't seem to get the drive to mount.

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  You've only mentioned a hardware issue with a drive, but have not made any mention of Ubuntu or any flavor of Ubuntu that this Q&A site is about.   Have you looked into the health of the drive (`smartctl` etc) to see what is the drive's condition according to the drive (and not just visual/audible observations), but I would suggest a link on how this relates to Ubuntu otherwise it's off-topic.

Comment: Some external drives use an encryption prevent the drive from being installed internally.  I am not sure if your drive falls into that category or not:  https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=15150  There is also a chance that the drive itself is bad.  Best to put it back in the enclosure and contact or troubleshoot it with Western Digital.

Comment: It doesn't populate with smartctl

Comment: It sounds like the drive is totally inaccessible, yes? Some drives that have been in an external enclosure won't work directly on a SATA port, due to the chip found on the enclosure's internal USB to SATA module. Now... as crazy as this sounds... reinstall the drive into the external enclosure, but do not put the full enclosure case back on... leave the drive visible... then place the enclosure/drive into the `freezer`... for about 1/2 hour... then remove it from the `freezer`, and `quickly connect` it to the computer and see if you can recover any data from it. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema very interesting, I'll try it tomorrow and let you know how it went!

Comment: What appears in dmesg & syslog when connecting & trying to mount the drive? What was it disappearing from after a few minutes, `/dev/sdX`? How were you trying to mount it, and what were the errors?

Comment: I forgot to ask... does the external HDD enclosure have it's own power supply, or is it just a straight USB enclosure? It makes a difference with a 2TB HDD. USB alone won't provide enough power.

Comment: The enclosure does have its own power supply that doesn't seem to be working either- I'll try with a dock and see what happens!

Comment: @LexITSol please start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I'll probably miss them. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema no luck with the dock, on either Ubuntu or windows. Freezing method didn't work either.

Comment: @LexITSol the dock has its own power supply, yes? Do you have a desktop machine with SATA ports that you can connect the drive to? Something isn't right here. It's too early for a 2TB to go bad this way.

Comment: @heynnema yes, the dock does have its own power. I've connected it internally to two machines with no luck. I've swapped the PCB with a similar drive, but it wouldn't even spin up with that. So frustrating! I feel like it should work, but just isn't ..

Comment: @LexITSol I guess that you've just got a bad drive. Depending on the manufacturer, there still may be some warranty left. Pursue that angle, if you like.